# 野原みたいで素敵でしょう？ De purpose

Tags: particle-で, copula

> 野原みたいで素敵でしょう？
> 野原みたい素敵でしょう？

Can anyone explain the nuance added by de here?  I feel like it may be a conjunctive copula, or perhaps it is meant to be a location marker?  I'm not sure if it means "At somewhere like a field would be wonderful wouldn't it?" or if it means "It's something like a field, and it's wonderful isn't it?"

Answer (score 2):

Your second sentence 「野原みたい素敵でしょう？」 sounds ungrammatical.

> 野原みたい**で**素敵でしょう？

According to 明鏡国語辞典, the で is part of 「みたいで」, which is the continuative form (連用形) of the auxiliary 「みたいだ」:

> みたいだ 〘助動　形動型〙｟みたいだろ‐みたいだっ・みたいで・みたいに‐みたいだ‐みたいな‐みたいなら‐○｠

So the sentence consists of:

> (omitted subject が) 野原みたいだ。 + 素敵だ。 + ～う？
> (omitted subject) is like a field. + is wonderful. + ~~ right?